# Crystal Reports "Object Size and Position" is not working

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

When I set the object size and position, sometimes [Crystal Reports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) changes it. For example:

X: 0.1, y: 0.1, Width: 1.9, Height: 0.133

Changes to

x: 0.1, y: 0.139, width: 1.9, height 0.094

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

File->Options under layout, at 'Grid options', make sure you uncheck 'Snap To Grid'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option called `Lock Size/Position` on the toolbar.

[image]

**Update**

Also goto `File->Options` and under layout, check what is the value for ***Grid Size***

Comment: All that does it make it so that I can't change it. When I type in a value and click ok it does not take

Comment: @Nick: Did you look at the `grid-size` set on your `crystal reports` ??

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Watch those pentagon-shaped marks on the ruler. They appear on the top and on the left. They've screw me up more times than I really want to admit.
2. The uncheck "snap to grid" comment above has gotten me a couple of times.
3. I sometimes put in a blank text field to help set the height of a detail line. If you are superimposing data on a form, it helps. Make certain that you put that on the left side. If you put it on the right side, for some reason Crystal Reports keeps changing the height on you by a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to get the "boxes" to move.  I was copying and pasting the Y value, but it would not change.

So I selected the box moved, it up with the arrow key, and pasted the Y value.  It worked!!!

Comment: This did work for me. I selected the box and moved it with the arrow key.  And then I could manually set the size and position values and they finally stayed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it isn't snapping to guidelines.  Asenine as it sounds, they will sometimes jump to guidelines near the values you enter (which kind of defeats the purpose of typing in the values).  I had this problem, and once I deleted all guidelines, it went away.

Comment: Re *"Asenine"*: Do you mean *[Asinine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asinine#Adjective)*?